# App Keeps Crashing When I'm trying to add two editext

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

please the app keeps crashing on my phone when i try to add the values of two edit text in android studio
i've tried all i can changing the data types

```
package com.example.danculator
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var addbtn: Button
lateinit var fnum: EditText
lateinit var snum: EditText
lateinit var ans: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
      addbtn=findViewById(R.id.add) as Button
        fnum=findViewById(R.id.fnum) as EditText
        snum=findViewById(R.id.snum) as EditText
        ans=findViewById(R.id.ans) as EditText
       addbtn.setOnClickListener {
           ans.setText(fnum.text.toString().toInt() + snum.text.toString().toInt())

       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `setText(int)` that expects a resource id but rather use `setText(CharSequence)`. That is, convert your `Int` computation to result to a `String`:

```
ans.setText((fnum.text.toString().toInt() + snum.text.toString().toInt()).toString())
```

Also, for future reference, examining the crash stacktrace should be the first step when trying to figure out what is wrong. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

I never used Kotlin before,but take a look at this part of code:

```
ans.setText(fnum.text.toString().toInt() + snum.text.toString().toInt())
```

In this part you are sum two integer values and want to set them as text for ans while you should use a string value for ans.So you should convert this to string again:

```
ans.setText((fnum.text.toString().toInt() + snum.text.toString().toInt()).toString())
```